# What are the lower computation and memory cheap fractal symmetric encryption algorimths?

Tags: encryption, symmetric

I would like to know about encryption schemes that are based in Fractal theory, while they have decent security and are pretty fast.

Comment: Shouldn't you also ask about their security?  After all, if you don't care about security, there are some really fast "encryption" schemes out there...

Comment: @poncho I think OP ask that the scheme is decent secure want he says "decent". Or do you think that a unsecure system would be "decent"?

Comment: Encryption that's pretty fast; decently secure; based on Fractal theory? Pick any two or I can't answer.

Comment: The empty set (there is no such encryption) is an answer.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus There is just one empty set, why are you saying one specific?

Comment: The empty set contains all the answers I know of fulfilling the criteria of being fast, secure, and based on fractal theory. There may be answers I don't yet know of, likely because they're undiscovered. More likely there aren't any other answers.